# How to parse ZoomifyImageFormat image?

Tags: javascript, zoomify

Sorry for my english :)

I have a problem with parsing images from one site. They are uses zoomify.com products. On network tab (chrome dev tools) it gets .zif files with postfix, like:
"/abc/file.zif?t1474131368079n22". How to get original JPEG image, knowing "/abc/file.zif" file (without postfixes).

example:
http://www.sunnybrookrvresort.com/Zoomify5/10-ZIF-OneFileStorage.htm

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Since ZIF is a subformat of [BigTIFF](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Zoomify_ZIF), you should be able to get the original by changing the extension to TIF (/abc/file.tif) and open it in Photoshop or other photo editors.  Afterwards, you could save it in other formats such as JPEG.

Here's what I got based on the example you provided:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df5Ly.jpg